# Use member functions directly with unordered_set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

Is there a short-cut to using `std::unordered_set` with classes that implement `operator==` and `hash`?  Specifically, is there a way to (1) avoid creating a stand-alone `operator==(const Object& a, const Object& b)` function, and (2) avoid defining an entire class just to hold `size_t operator()(const Object& o) const {return o.hash();}`

Of course, neither of these are problems, I'm just curious.

Comment: when you say "class that implements hash" do you mean as a member function, or a free function?

Answer (score 2):

1. `operator==` being defined as a member function is already catered for.
2. If the class being used as a key has a member function `hash() const` then we can do something simple like this:

-

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

struct myclass {
  std::size_t hash() const { return 0; }
  bool operator==(const myclass& r) const { return true; }
};

struct self_hash
{
  template<class T>
  auto operator()(const T& r) const { return r.hash(); }
};

int main()
{

  using mymap = std::unordered_map<myclass, std::string, self_hash>;

  auto m = mymap();
}
```